# Can you use multiple catch with same exception

Tags: java, spring, exception, try-catch

```
public function() {
        try {
            // execute code and if error jump into  1st catch
            return output;
        } catch (Exception e){
          //execute code and if error jump in 2nd catch
          return output1
        } catch (Exception e){
          //execute code and stop
          return output 2
        }   
}
```

The Above is the Code flow I want to achieve, I wanted to check if there is way or better way to do my scenario where I want to try a piece of code and if it fails, catch and execute first catch piece of code and if it again fails and exception occurs in first catch also go for final piece of code in last catch. Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here is the flow I want to achieve :
**try  ----if error/exception----> catch1 ----if error/exception----> catch2**

Comment: No, you instead need a nested try within your first catch.

Comment: What you have so far, with multiple catch statements is used when you are looking for specific errors to catch. If you have *n* catches, your first through *n*-1 catch statements will be more specific, like `catch (IntegrityError e)`. Your nth catch will be a general `catch (Exception e)`

Comment: You also have the `finally` part of a catch statement, but that is something that is executed ***no matter what*** after your try/catch block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that. To catch a exception inside a catch block you should user another try/catch.

```java
public function() {
    try {
        return output;
    } catch (Exception e){
        try {
            return output1;
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            return output2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, my bad I didn't know we can write some nested try-catch